# Change white window and menu background the lxappearance had no effect on

Tags: lxde, desktop-background

I use Lubuntu 18.04 and changed system colors with LXAppearance using customized color scheme. Most of the installed software, main menu and PCManFM file manager accepted the color change, however Gnome Software, Gnome Disks, Graphical Synaptic Package Manager, Abiword, Firefox Browser and SMPlayer colors did not change (showing bright blinding white background and light blue as the menu selection color). How to change the white #FFFFFF background to my preferred gray #808080 and light blue menu selection color to navy blue? Thank you.
I just added 2 screenshots of the apps that accepted the color change and 2 screenshots of the apps that did not accept the color scheme change. I am trying to achieve neutral gray color scheme, that is easy on the eyes. Bright white background is blinding.
[image: color-accepted1][image: color-accepted2][image: color-NOT-accepted1][image: color-NOT-accepted2]

Comment: Can you get a couple of screenshots to show the differences and add an arrow or two (if it's not abundantly clear with just the screenshots)?

Comment: The LXDE desktop is GTK2, the programs you are complaining about will ignore GTK2 settings as they obey GNOME's GTK3 settings only.  LXDE started being ported to GTK3 (Pcman the creator of `pcmanfm` which is the file manager, plus handles the visible desktop of LXDE) first ported it to GTK3 but noted a huge drop in performance, so it was then ported to Qt5 which had a far less performance hit; this resulted in the now supported `pcmanfm-qt` Lubuntu has used since 18.10. To make changes for the GNOME programs, you'll need to change settings within GNOME itself.

Comment: I note `onboard` is obeying the Openbox settings though, in contrast to `pavucontrol` which ignores neither openbox window border settings, nor LXDE's GTK2 appearance settings for colors etc.  You maybe able to improve some GTK3 programs, but you can't do much for core GNOME apps (like `pavucontrol` in your example outside of GNOME tweaks or settings.

Comment: I found a solution to my problem. It is Q4OS Linux OS with Trinity Desktop Environment. It is also based on Debian, so I can use Synaptic to install software, much more customizable than LXDE and only uses around 200 MB more RAM than LXDE, but takes way less disk space (around 2 GB for base system). Lubuntu takes around 6 GB. All my apps accepted all chosen colors.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to install Adwaita-dark theme, which includes GTK2, GTK3 and GNOME shell  themes. All programs are now look the same and no more white background. The screenshot shows my custom modification of the Adwaita-grey-dark theme.[image]